# How to upload file from client to DB with GraphQL and mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, upload, graphql, gridfs

i'm trying to upload a file from my client (React/GraphQL) to MongoDB. I use gridFSBucket for that, but i've got a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error with this code:

```js
  async upload(request, { id, file }) {
    const {
      filename, createReadStream,
    } = await file[0];
    const bucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, { bucketName: 'uploads' });
    const uploadStream = bucket.openUploadStream(filename);
    createReadStream()
      .pipe(uploadStream)
      .on('error', console.log('error'))
      .on('finish', console.log('finish'));
    return { filename };
  }
```

To fix this, I'll apparently have to go through Node 12, but I'd rather not...

Can I fix this another way? If not, how else can I upload?

Answer (score 0):

Update fs-capacitor (graphql-upload dependencies) to 3.0.0 to fix the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` problem